expo Taskmanager stopps after 5 minutes on android
I am building an expo app that should start tracking mainly in the background - its intended for outdoor sports. It works perfectly on IOS, starts tracking and the task happily gets triggered in the background every 20 seconds. But android just stopps after 5 minutes or after the user dont move for a short while.
Any help is appreciated!!
Here's the relevant part of the code:
Background task definition (global scope):
const LOCATION_TASK_NAME = 'background-location-task';

TaskManager.defineTask(LOCATION_TASK_NAME, async ({ data, error }) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error(`ERROR FROM TASKMANAGER: ${error.message}`);
    return;
  }
  let lastLocations = await getLastLocationsFromStorage('lastLocations');
  if (data) {
    const { locations } = data;
    lastLocations = lastLocations.concat(lastLocations, locations);
    if (lastLocations.length > 50) {
      lastLocations = lastLocations.slice(-50);
    }
    await storeLastLocations(lastLocations);
    //console.log(`Last locations length:${lastLocations.length}`);
    try {
      await locationUpload(locations);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error.message);
      throw (error);
    }
  }
});

The code inside a Context file used in the app:
const startTracking = async () => {
    try {
        console.log('Starting background location task...');
        await Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync(LOCATION_TASK_NAME, {
          accuracy: Location.Accuracy.High,
          //activityType: Location.ActivityType.Fitness,
          timeInterval: 20000,
          distanceInterval: 20,
          deferredUpdatesDistance: 20,
          deferredUpdatesInterval: 20000,
          showsBackgroundLocationIndicator: true
        });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error.message);
    }
};


